# How to fix mat-accordion title issue in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I read multiple blogs and search a lot on google, but I am still not able to fix the below CSS issue that is in `Angular material`.
I need your help to fix this CSS issue.

**Desktop view**
[image]

**Mobile View**

[image]

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: Share your code to detect the problem.

Comment: @Abdelrahman this is just copy paste from the official website.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this issue. Here is the SCSS that I used to fix my issue.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .mat-expansion-panel {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 64px);

    &-header {
      height: auto;
      padding: 6px 12px;
    }

    &-body {
      padding: 16px;
    }
  }
}
```

**Final Result**

[image]